# R: How would you convert a matrix into a list with a single element?

Tags: r, list, function, matrix, vector

**Data:**

```
input1 <- matrix(c(2, 15))
input2 <- list(5, integer(0), c(5, 6))
```

I have a matrix (input1) that looks like this:

```
         [,1]
[1,]    2
[2,]   15
```

I want to convert it into a list object that looks like this:

```
[[1]]
[1] 2 15
```

What's the best way of doing this?

It would also be useful if the function could take a list like this (input2) as an input and not make any changes to it:

```
[[1]]
[1] 5

[[2]]
integer(0)

[[3]]
[1]  5 16

[[4]]
[1] 9

[[5]]
integer(0)
```

Comment: ? Do you mean `list(as.vector(matrix(c(2,15))))`

Comment: That works for the first part of the question but if I put input2 into this it doesn't stay in the same format as I'd like in the second part of the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a function to do that -

```
change_matrix_to_list <- function(x) {
  if(inherits(x, 'matrix')) list(c(x))
  else x
}

input1 <- matrix(c(2, 15))
input2 <- list(5, integer(0), c(5, 6))

change_matrix_to_list(input1)

#[[1]]
#[1]  2 15

change_matrix_to_list(input2)

#[[1]]
#[1] 5

#[[2]]
#integer(0)

#[[3]]
#[1] 5 6
```

This checks if the input has a class `'matrix'` then change it to list or else keep it as it is.